# How do I install the facebook sdk in a react native application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook, react-native

I followed the instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#app-delegate), but I couldn't get step 5 with connecting app delegate to work because the instructions are in Objective C, whereas my AppDelegate file is written in Swift.

I tried this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    // Add any custom logic here.
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: (UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey & id)) -> Bool {
    let handled: Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey], annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
    // Add any custom logic here.
    return handled
}
```

Which produces this build error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/kevinchiang/jh-mobile/ios/JustHive/Appdelegate.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

I am unfamiliar with Swift and Obj-C, so I assume there may be something wrong with my Swift code.

Comment: Your second function is wrong. I think you want to use this method [application(_:open:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application) instead of the one you have there. Let me know if it works

Comment: Can you show me what you mean? I tried func application(_ application: UIApplication, _:open:options: (UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey & id)) and it didn't work

Comment: did my answer helped you?? if it did mark it as correct ty.

Answer (score 0):

In your function you had that the type of the parameter options was `(UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey & id)` which it doesnt exist you should have look for its equivalent in Swift which is this one [application(_:open:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application) as you can see [options](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/uiapplicationopenurloptionskey) is a dictionary that contains multiple elements to correctly use the FB sdk you have to use the keys corresponding to the options annotations and options source application so you can use it correctly.

So answering your question should change your second func for the one below. Let me know how it goes.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, 
              open url: URL, 
               options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool{ 
    let handled: Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(applic‌​ation, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication], annotation: options[.annotation])
    return handled 
}
```

You could also simplify the code above removing the variable handle and it will look like this.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, 
              open url: URL, 
               options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool{ 

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(applic‌​ation, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication], annotation: options[.annotation])

}
```